# Merging 2 Data.frame by equal distribution of Rows in R

Tags: r, dplyr, merge, mergesort

I have two data frame `df_1` and `df_2` of more than 5000 observations (rows). I want to merge them based on two similar columns as `Date` and `Mcode`, in such a way that rows are equally distributed in both data frames. See below for details.

```
>df_1
 Date      Mcode    TNo. BSize
1  1/8/2014 3R72B7K8ZN 1426576   7.2
2  1/8/2014 3R72B7K8ZN 1426578   7.5
3  1/8/2014 3R72B7K8ZN 1426579   7.5
4  1/8/2014 8R55BNW9H5 1426581   7.2
5  1/8/2014 8R55BNW9H5 1426582   7.5
6  1/8/2014 8R55BNW9H5 1426584   7.5
7  1/8/2014 3R72B7K8ZN 1426606   7.5
8  1/8/2014 3R72B7K8ZN 1426610   7.2
9  1/8/2014 8R55BNW9H5 1426621   7.5
10 1/8/2014 8R55BNW9H5 1426624   7.5
11 2/8/2014 4R72B7K9ZN 1426626   7.5
12 2/8/2014 4R72B7K9ZN 1426627   7.5
13 2/8/2014 8R55BNW9H5 1426638   7.2
14 2/8/2014 8R55BNW9H5 1426639   7.2
15 2/8/2014 4R60B6K6ZN 1426699   7.5
16 3/8/2014 4R60B6K6ZN 1426701   1.5
17 3/8/2014 4R72B7K9ZN 1426703   7.5
18 3/8/2014 4R60B6K6ZN 1426704   7.5
19 3/8/2014 4R72B7K9ZN 1426705   7.5
20 3/8/2014 4R72B7K9ZN 1426706   7.2
```

AND similarly second data frame is as follow.

```
>df_2
   Date      Mcode X28days X7days
1  1/8/2014 3R72B7K8ZN    64.0   51.1
2  1/8/2014 3R72B7K8ZN    65.0   51.6
3  1/8/2014 8R55BNW9H5    75.4   58.4
4  1/8/2014 8R55BNW9H5    78.7   57.1
5  2/8/2014 4R72B7K9ZN    75.7   58.8
6  2/8/2014 4R72B7K9ZN    73.9   56.9
7  2/8/2014 8R55BNW9H5    77.3   60.8
8  2/8/2014 4R60B6K6ZN    62.6   48.5
9  3/8/2014 4R72B7K9ZN    71.2   56.1
10 4/8/2014 4R60B6K6ZN    59.3   46.8
11 4/8/2014 4R60B6K7ZN    68.5   51.2
```

I want to merge `df_1` and `df_2` such that a resulting `df_3` (having same no. of rows as that of `df_1`) should be as follow

```
>df_3
       Date      Mcode    TNo. BSize X28days X7days
1  1/8/2014 3R72B7K8ZN 1426576   7.2    64.0   51.1
2  1/8/2014 3R72B7K8ZN 1426578   7.5    64.0   51.1
3  1/8/2014 3R72B7K8ZN 1426579   7.5    64.0   51.1
4  1/8/2014 8R55BNW9H5 1426581   7.2    75.4   58.4
5  1/8/2014 8R55BNW9H5 1426582   7.5    75.4   58.4
6  1/8/2014 8R55BNW9H5 1426584   7.5    75.4   58.4
7  1/8/2014 3R72B7K8ZN 1426606   7.5    65.0   51.6
8  1/8/2014 3R72B7K8ZN 1426610   7.2    65.0   51.6
9  1/8/2014 8R55BNW9H5 1426621   7.5    78.7   57.1
10 1/8/2014 8R55BNW9H5 1426624   7.5    78.7   57.1
11 2/8/2014 4R72B7K9ZN 1426626   7.5    75.7   58.8
12 2/8/2014 4R72B7K9ZN 1426627   7.5    75.7   58.8
13 2/8/2014 8R55BNW9H5 1426638   7.2    77.3   60.8
14 2/8/2014 8R55BNW9H5 1426639   7.2    77.3   60.8
15 2/8/2014 4R60B6K6ZN 1426699   7.5    62.6   48.5
16 3/8/2014 4R60B6K6ZN 1426701   1.5      NA     NA
17 3/8/2014 4R72B7K9ZN 1426703   7.5    71.2   56.1
18 3/8/2014 4R60B6K6ZN 1426704   7.5      NA     NA
19 3/8/2014 4R72B7K9ZN 1426705   7.5    71.2   56.1
20 3/8/2014 4R72B7K9ZN 1426706   7.2    71.2   56.1
```

if we run `df_3%>%filter(Date=="1/8/2014", Mcode=="3R72B7K8ZN")`, it gives

```
      Date      Mcode    TNo. BSize X28days X7days
1 1/8/2014 3R72B7K8ZN 1426576   7.2      64   51.1
2 1/8/2014 3R72B7K8ZN 1426578   7.5      64   51.1
3 1/8/2014 3R72B7K8ZN 1426579   7.5      64   51.1
4 1/8/2014 3R72B7K8ZN 1426606   7.5      65   51.6
5 1/8/2014 3R72B7K8ZN 1426610   7.2      65   51.6
```

see
The first two row of `df_2` is equally distributed in final or merge data set of `df_3`. A similar pattern of merging can be seen for all rows.
Note:
I want this type of merging for full data sets of having size greater than 30x5000 (col x row).
in full data
The dates are for years of 2014 and 2015 (more than 700 dates) and Mcode have more than 30 different types.

Anyone who can help me regarding, I shall be very grateful.

Comment: You mentioned "merge them based on two similar columns as Date and Mcode". But looks like both dataframes have duplicate values in both, how would you want the merged result to be of same row length as first dataframe?

Comment: this is the main issue, duplication makes problem in equal distribution of rows, that why i am here, yes the final data's length should be equal to first data frame with larger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this could be to add an additional id column to both of your dataframes.
I'll call it `obs_id` here. This id is set within each group of `Date` and `Mcode`, to count up to maximum the number of observations in the respective other dataframe and then "reset" from 1.
This would look as follows:

```
library(dplyr)

df_1a <- df_1 %>%
  left_join(
    df_2 %>% count(Date, Mcode, name = "df_2_obs_n"),
    by = c("Date", "Mcode")
  ) %>%
  group_by(Date, Mcode) %>%
  mutate(
    obs_id = first(df_2_obs_n) %>%
      coalesce(0) %>%
      seq() %>%
      rep(length.out = n())
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-df_2_obs_n)

df_2a <- df_2 %>%
  left_join(
    df_1a %>% count(Date, Mcode, name = "df_1_obs_n"),
    by = c("Date", "Mcode")
  ) %>%
  group_by(Date, Mcode) %>%
  mutate(
    obs_id = first(df_1_obs_n) %>%
      coalesce(0) %>%
      seq() %>%
      rep(length.out = n())
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-df_1_obs_n)
```

For your example group of `Date=="1/8/2014", Mcode=="3R72B7K8ZN"` this generates the column like this:

```
> df_1a %>% filter(Date=="1/8/2014", Mcode=="3R72B7K8ZN")
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  Date     Mcode         TNo. BSize obs_id
  <chr>    <chr>        <int> <dbl>  <int>
1 1/8/2014 3R72B7K8ZN 1426576   7.2      1
2 1/8/2014 3R72B7K8ZN 1426578   7.5      2
3 1/8/2014 3R72B7K8ZN 1426579   7.5      1
4 1/8/2014 3R72B7K8ZN 1426606   7.5      2
5 1/8/2014 3R72B7K8ZN 1426610   7.2      1

> df_2a %>% filter(Date=="1/8/2014", Mcode=="3R72B7K8ZN")
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  Date     Mcode      X28days X7days obs_id
  <chr>    <chr>        <dbl>  <dbl>  <int>
1 1/8/2014 3R72B7K8ZN      64   51.1      1
2 1/8/2014 3R72B7K8ZN      65   51.6      2
```

Now, you can left join based on that column and you will see the columns from `df_2a` to be "distributed evenly", at least as much as you seem to expect it.

```
df_3a <- df_1a %>%
  left_join(df_2a, by = c("Date", "Mcode", "obs_id"))

> df_3a %>% filter(Date=="1/8/2014", Mcode=="3R72B7K8ZN")
# A tibble: 5 x 7
  Date     Mcode         TNo. BSize obs_id X28days X7days
  <chr>    <chr>        <int> <dbl>  <int>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1 1/8/2014 3R72B7K8ZN 1426576   7.2      1      64   51.1
2 1/8/2014 3R72B7K8ZN 1426578   7.5      2      65   51.6
3 1/8/2014 3R72B7K8ZN 1426579   7.5      1      64   51.1
4 1/8/2014 3R72B7K8ZN 1426606   7.5      2      65   51.6
5 1/8/2014 3R72B7K8ZN 1426610   7.2      1      64   51.1
```

Due to the `obs_id` being repeated in the pattern `1,2,1,2,1` in `df_1a`, the order in which the table rows from `df_2a` are joined is different from the `df_3` you have described above. If that is a problem, you can tweak the `rep(...)` call a little like this:

```
df_1b <- df_1 %>%
  left_join(
    df_2 %>%
      count(Date, Mcode, name = "df_2_obs_n"),
    by = c("Date", "Mcode")
  ) %>%
  group_by(Date, Mcode) %>%
  mutate(
    df_2_obs_n = coalesce(df_2_obs_n, 1),
    obs_id = first(df_2_obs_n) %>%
      seq() %>%
      rep(length.out = n(), each = ceiling(n()/first(df_2_obs_n)))
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-df_2_obs_n)

df_2b <- df_2 %>%
  left_join(
    df_1a %>%
      count(Date, Mcode, name = "df_1_obs_n"),
    by = c("Date", "Mcode")
  ) %>%
  group_by(Date, Mcode) %>%
  mutate(
    df_1_obs_n = coalesce(df_1_obs_n, 1),
    obs_id = first(df_1_obs_n) %>%
      seq() %>%
      rep(length.out = n(), each = ceiling(n()/first(df_1_obs_n)))
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-df_1_obs_n)
```

Now, the `obs_id` repeat pattern is `1,1,1,2,2` and you're getting the result you described.

```
df_3b <- df_1b %>%
    left_join(df_2b, by = c("Date", "Mcode", "obs_id"))

> df_3b %>% filter(Date=="1/8/2014", Mcode=="3R72B7K8ZN")
# A tibble: 5 x 7
  Date     Mcode         TNo. BSize obs_id X28days X7days
  <chr>    <chr>        <int> <dbl>  <int>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1 1/8/2014 3R72B7K8ZN 1426576   7.2      1      64   51.1
2 1/8/2014 3R72B7K8ZN 1426578   7.5      1      64   51.1
3 1/8/2014 3R72B7K8ZN 1426579   7.5      1      64   51.1
4 1/8/2014 3R72B7K8ZN 1426606   7.5      2      65   51.6
5 1/8/2014 3R72B7K8ZN 1426610   7.2      2      65   51.6
```

Comment: you are great sir, Thank you very very much, i am beginner in R so its difficult to digest this huge code but i tried. its working and now i am gonna play with to get understand it fully. Again bundle of thanks to you

Comment: Happy to hear. Let me know if you have any further questions. Also, if the answer solved your problem, feel free to upvote & accept it :)

Comment: oh sorry forgot to accept and vote, i am new @ stack, now have done it thanks

Comment: sir it was running in one of the data sets but now it's giving an error
like when i run first set it give error
df_1a <- df_1 %>%
  left_join(
    df_2 %>% count(Date, MIX, name = "df_2_obs_n"),
    by = c("Date", "MIX")
  ) %>%
  group_by(Date, MIX) %>%
  mutate(
    obs_id = first(df_2_obs_n) %>%
      coalesce(0) %>%
      seq() %>%
      rep(length.out = n())
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-df_2_obs_n)

Error: Argument 2 must be an integer vector, not a double vector

Comment: Um, not sure why this occurs, if you haven't added some intermediate step.. best, you wrap `first(df_2_obs_n)` in an `as.integer` and change 0 to integer-typed 0L in the `coalesce` (so, `coalesce(0L)`) to avoid a type clash.